# Can't get canel button on search input jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I work with search input field, and i have issues with getting cancel button, i want to set some actions for cancel icon, but this button is not working, for some reason.

My code - [jsFidle](https://jsfiddle.net/qunzorez/bnq4g7hw/4/)

HTML:

```
<div class="search-field">
    <input name="search" placeholder="Search.." class="search-input" />
    <span class="cancel-icon"></span>
    <div class="search-module">
        <div id="search-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Specifically, you don't have a problem "getting" the *cancel* button https://jsfiddle.net/bw0dfx8m/ - you have a problem *clicking* it.  You can't click it because your css makes it hide before the mouse event fires.

Comment: @freedomn-m how i can fix this?

Comment: $(".cancel-icon").on("mousedown", - try with this... https://jsfiddle.net/6nuvb024/